# What are the markings on this PCB?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, identification, gerber, markings

[image]

[image]

I have an E322822 circuit board with the markings of A.F.054.5/04  08_03. Wat do those markings mean? How do I get the Gerber file for this board?

Comment: Those markings may be PCB manufacturer- or designer- or even product manufacturer-related. I'm not sure if the PCB manufacturer or the product designer would be happy to share the gerber files with random people unless they are free for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It appears to be an [industrial control board made by Siemens, which may include a Modbus interface.](https://www.marineindustrialmachinery.com/product/siemens-e322822-pcb-circuit)
2. You'd have to ask Siemens what the markings mean, or find a circuit diagram or device guide that explains it.  Good luck.
3. Ask Siemens.  They are unlikely to provide you with Gerber files though (unless you can cart up enough wheelbarrows full of cash to make it worth their while.) Failing enough wheelbarrows full of cash, you could recreate the layout using any of the freely available PCB design packages.

---

Now that you've added photos, it is clear that it is not the Siemens board I linked to.

The one you have is relatively simple.  If you were an experienced user of an electronics design package, you  could draw up a copy and generate the needed Gerber file(s) easily.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP. WHERE CAN I GET PCB DESIGN PACKAGES?

Comment: @Darren:  I use [KiCad.](https://www.kicad.org/)  Free in all senses of the word.

Comment: Fair warning:  It is going to be a lot of work.

Comment: Oh wow really! I need a new board urgently that is exactly the same as the one I have got.

Comment: The link I posted is for someone selling those boards.  It might be faster and easier to locate a used baord than to try to copy it.

Comment: [Does your board look like this?](https://www.radwell.de/en-GB/Buy/K%20TRON/K%20TRON/E322822/?redirect=true)  They claim to have various versions, so might be able to match the one you need replaced.

Comment: is there a way i can send pictures on here? so that i can show you the board

Comment: You can edit your question to add pictures.

Comment: i have added the pictures

Comment: Are those Pictures fine?

Comment: @Darren There are scanners which can be used to scan simple layouts such as this directly into the PCB CAD. You could look to hire a PCB layout consultant who owns such a scanner. Although a simple 2 layer thing like this might be scannable with a simple photo scanner and then look to convert from jpeg to dwg or some such.

Answer (score 1):

The markings are not very relevant. This is a 4-layer board and you'll have to reverse-engineer it, i.e. figure out the connections, and re-draw it using KiCad (realistically). The board looks to be designed to deal with mains voltages, so it requires attention to clearance and creepage distances. Unless you have the time and willingness to learn all about it in a short time, you might be best served getting a consultant engineer to copy the board for you. Should take a day's worth of work at most.

The board has been damaged due to improper procedure when desoldering the components. There's plenty of delamination both within the board and between the board and the pads.